# MVC 4 Razor view Dynamically rendering Anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to render dynamic HTML consisting of anchor tags, but its not rendering correctly on browser.

Code :

```
                    @{string str = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.DynamicHTML);
                    Html.Raw(str)
```

Output :

```
                        <a&nbsp;href="http: www.test.com="" categories=""                 test Category"=""><strong>test Category</strong> </a&nbsp;href="http:> }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help before posting your next question/answer.

Comment: What is the content of `DynamicHTML`?

Comment: <a href="http://www.test.com/Categories/TestCategory"><strong>Test Category</strong></a>

Comment: Post exactly what your code is. And post the part you are giving the `DynamicHTML` value, as in your code. Because the code you posted, won't compile. There's a missing `}`. And, there is no way to MVC to render your previous comment, into what you mentioned in question. Unless there is a different. Post exact code please.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some problems with proper escaping of your string. I tried the following (note that the double-quotes for the href attribute are escaped):

```
@{ 
    var str = Convert.ToString(@"<a href=""test.com/Categories/TestCategory""><strong> Test Category </strong></a>");
}
@Html.Raw(str)
```

and this wrote a valid HTML output

```
<a href="test.com/Categories/TestCategory"><strong> Test Category </strong></a>
```

Comment: When we hardcode link then its working fine, but when you try to load from viewbag it gets messed up.

Comment: Please show the code that creates the string and fills the `DynamicHtml` in the ViewBag as Javad has suggested, then we can take a closer look.